# Why aren't selected items showing up in my owner drawn listview control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am making an owner drawn listview, in which I am drawing shapes inside of a listview. 
I have done this using `Listview_DrawItem` event.
My problem is that when I run the application, I can't select the shapes drawn in the listview.

```
private void AddItem(ListView lvw, string Shape_name, Color Shape_color)
    {
        // Make the item.
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(Shape_name);

        // Save the Shape object  in the Tag property.
        Shapes myShape = new Shapes(Shape_name,Shape_color);

        item.Tag = myShape;
        item.SubItems[0].Name ="ShapeName";

        // Add subitems so they can draw.
        item.SubItems.Add("ShapeColor");

        // Add the item to the ListView.
        lvw.Items.Add(item);
    }


    // Draw the item. In this case, the Shape_name's logo.
    private void lvwServers_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {

        // Get the ListView item and the Shapes object.
        ListViewItem item = e.Item;

        Shapes myShape = item.Tag as Shapes;

        // Clear.
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Smoothing mode for blur free drawing
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 10, e.Bounds.Top + 10, 41, 41);


        using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(myShape.ShapeColor))
        {

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, rect);
        }

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);

        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
```

Also, I can't change values of `e.bound` property.

Comment: You can not change `e.Bounds`, it is a read-only property telling you the bounds on the item. Also, what do you mean by 'can't select shapes'. What happens when you select them? How do you know they're not being selected?

Comment: To expound on what Rotem said, you aren't handling the state of the individual items, therefore you are probably selecting the items, but just can't see the effects as you're not drawing them. The selection doesn't happen automatically, you have to draw it.

Comment: Do you have the `SelectEntireRow` property set to `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can base the drawing code in your DrawItem event handler on the value of e.State which is available in the DrawListViewItemEventArgs parameter.

```
bool isSelected = e.State == ListViewItemStates.Selected;
```

That way you can decide which elements of the drawn item you wish to change when an item is selected.

Comment: This is not good form. The state can have more than one flag set. The correct syntax is `e.State.HasFlag(ListViewItemStates.Selected)`.